# how to prevent vba userform textbox from adding additional line return when extracting text

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have a userform with multiple textboxes that all allow for multiline entry.  When I extract text from the textboxes, the data is collected with 2x line returns between each item instead of the one line return as entered.

this would be my code

```
sub commandbutton1_click()
    activesheet.Range("A1").text=textbox1.text
end sub
```

when I enter data into textbox1 (either from typing it OR pasting from clipboard), it looks like this:

1. apples (1x line return)
2. bananas (1x line return)
3. oranges (1x line return)
4. strawberries (1x line return)

However, when I extract this w/ commandbutton1 (to ultimately paste to a word doc) my result is:

1. apples (2x line returns)
2. bananas(2x line returns)
3. oranges(2x line returns)
4. strawberries(2x line returns)

But I want to look how it looked in the original textbox. Is this a textbox property that I'm missing or is there way to code around this?

I know that I can just use a word macro to fix this but was hoping to fix it in one step.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to check what characters these linebreaks actually consist of. On windows, normally a linebreak consists of two characters, carriage return (`vbCr`, `Chr(13)`) and linefeed (`vbLf`, `Chr(10)`). In vba there is also a constant representing both of these at once: `vbCrLf`. After you have analyzed your string, for example with this [tool](http://asciivalue.com/), you can get rid of the superfluous characters maybe like this: `activesheet.Range("A1").text=replace(textbox1.text, vbCr, "")`, or like this: `activesheet.Range("A1").text=replace(textbox1.text, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)`

Comment: Another option is to take your values from each textbox, trim them, and append to an array, then loop through your array and add any spacing, etc., you want.